# CSS - How to keep a fixed point on a resizeable image?

Tags: html, css

i am making a map with points. My project uses bootstrap, if that helps. As my map scales due to the screen size, my points move away, and aren't fixed in the same position in regards to their parent.

I presume i also need to scale down their size as the map gets smaller or larger, in order to keep it accurate. Is there a simple way of doing this?

```
.pin{
position: absolute;
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
margin: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #F06449;
animation-name: bounce;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-duration: 1s;
box-sizing:border-box;
transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
}

.map{
width: 40%;
height: 25%;
position: relative;
left: 56%;
background-color: #E5F9E0;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
   <div>
    <img src="img/output-onlinepngtools.png" class="map animated fadeIn slower" alt="Responsive image">
    <div id="mapPins">
        <span onclick="openOverlay()" class="pin" style="left: 60em; bottom: 30em"><p>Test</p></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected it. I should've done the following:

Create a div holder for just the image and additional information. Set both that and image to be relative, and the pin to be absolute. Eg:

```
     <div class = "mapContainer">
       <img src="img/output-onlinepngtools.png" class="animated fadeIn slower">
       <span onclick="openOverlay()" class="pin" style="top: 66.5%; left: 40%;"><p>Test</p></span>
     </div>
```

Then for my css:

```
.mapContainer{
position: relative;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 30%;
}

.mapContainer > img{
height: 60%;
width: 80%;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #E5F9E0;
}
```

With my pin now being set with absolute positioning, as well as percentages for position.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for it for several days...

Answer (score 1):

When a element have position: absolute you can use the top and left css properties. They also support percentage so you could do top: 45% and left: 15% to position the pin.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the position of both the pin and the map a position that's in percentages achieves the effect you want. Like this:

html:

```
<div class="test-background">
  <img src="img/output-onlinepngtools.png" class="map animated fadeIn slower" alt="Responsive image"/> 
  <div id="mapPins">
    <span onclick="openOverlay()" class="pin"><p>Test</p></span>
  </div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.pin{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
/*   give relative positioning */
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
}

.map{
  width: 40%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #E5F9E0;
}
```

Check it out here (added some background colors for clarity and remoevd some of the animation attributes that cluttered up the css): https://codepen.io/jasperdg/pen/oNNVNro

Comment: It doesn't work. Solution given by @TrueWinter works.